# Using third party designer softwares in Windows Forms Applications?

Tags: c#, telerik, infragistics

So I'm trying to redesign a simple window that has basic controls of Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2010. The question is can I use the Free Trial third party designer softwares (such as Telerik, Infragistics) to make few changes. Cause I don't need to buy it to make few change.

Also are there any conflicts with those third party controls between Windows Forms Applications? Cause my Application has so many operation and events after the controls.

Comment: This is legal question if a license allows particular activity. Should be answered by careful reading of the license or/and consulting lawyer. Note that most commercial licenses don't allow beta/trial versions to be used directly to produce production/commercial code.

Comment: No you can't use Telerik or Infragistics stuff in production if you don't buy a license. These companies get revenue from people who need to spend lots of $$$ in order to get anything decent out of winforms. I suggest WPF if you want a much more modern UI framework with advanced features. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and it does not support anything.

Comment: You can get features similar to Telerik or Infragistics controls for free from WPF and the WPF Toolkit, or create your own controls and styles easily, without having to resort to horrendous things like "owner draw" or "P/Invoke" (whatever that means)

Comment: @HighCore Most of the third party control companies also offer very cool controls in WPF, since it gives them a lot more flexibility.  You are basically paying them to do a lot of the leg work for you, so you can focus on your functionality.

Comment: @JohnKoerner right, but, based on the question, I can assume the OP cannot afford these licenses, therefore an option is to use WPF and create some nice looking styles, as opposed to using horrible, Windows 3.1-like winforms stuff

Comment: @mangasm The question isn't clear. Are looking to replace existing controls with controls from a third party like Infragistics?  If so then you would need a license for the toolset that you choose and Infragistics and Telerik will require that you purchase those licenses if you choose them.  As far as conflicts, the controls will work fine in a Windows Forms application though the object model will not be identical to the inbox controls and you will need to change which events are used and rewrite your code to make use of the new controls API.  If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions I had my solution